# windows azure service pack: how to configure admin authentication site

Tags: azure

I installed azure service pack and im trying to configure it. I'm getting this error- Admin Authentication Site: 500 Internal server error - Failed to configure databases and services: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: what data base did you use SQL server express/server/localdb? what are the steps you followed? could you update your question with these steps ?

Comment: I have the same result with SQL 2012 Developer Edition